# Conditionally set scrollbar button size

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I want to change the size of all scrollbars (arrow buttons and thumb) in my application, dependent on a condition. The condition is a bool variable (Settings.TouchScreenMode) in the ViewModel of the main window.
I would like to do it with a trigger, something like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Settings.TouchScreenMode, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ArrowButtonWidth" Value="30" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I found a way to set some `SystemParameters` but I cannot use this in a trigger, so the scrollbar is always changed and not only when my bool-value is true:

```
<system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">30</system:Double>
<system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}">30</system:Double>
<system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">30</system:Double>
<system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}">30</system:Double>
```

Is there a way to do this without replacing the entire control template of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage `LayoutTransform` to achieve the same

so just use `ScaleTransform` in `LayoutTransform` and everything is done for touch screen

eg

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ScrollBar Margin="4" />
    <ScrollBar Margin="4">
        <ScrollBar.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2"
                            ScaleY="2" />
        </ScrollBar.LayoutTransform>
    </ScrollBar>
</StackPanel>
```

result

[image: scrollbar magnification]

you may perhaps use as

```xml
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Settings.TouchScreenMode, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2"
                                    ScaleY="2" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just bind to the value using a value converter. However, you need to define your `boolToWidthConverter` in the `Resources`.

```
<Style>
        <Setter Property="ArrowButtonWidth" Value="{Binding Settings.TouchScreenMode, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}", Converter={StaticResource boolToWidthConverter} />

</Style>
```

**EDIT**:
Perhaps you could set those values programmatically.

```
public partial class GlobalResources : ResourceDictionary
{
    public GlobalResources()
    {
        this.Add("SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey", your_conditional_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: My basic problem is that there is no property like `ArrowButtonWidth` and I only could access the width by setting the system parameters or replacing the control template. But thanks anyway for the suggestion.